# VBA Application definied error in pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a PivotTable that selects items like xlPageField and PivotField, but I wish it would automatically select options for me in those filters. I wanted to add

```
   .CurrentPage = 1
```

But i got error there about Application definied or object error. I tried change to .CurrentPageName but not helped.

This is my part of code :

```
 With sh_d.PivotTables(tbName1)
  With .PivotFields("CRD_RWG")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
       .CurrentPage = 1
   With sh_d.PivotTables(tbName1)
  With .PivotFields("NEW_DEFAULT")
       .Orientation = xlPageField
       .Position = 1
       .CurrentPageName = Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions is a below :

```
 Dim wbMe As Workbook
    Dim sh_s As Worksheet, sh_d As Worksheet
    Set wbMe = ActiveWorkbook
   
    Set sh_s = wbMe.Sheets("kredyty")
    lr1 = sh_s.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ptver1 = 6
    tbName1 = "Tabela przestawna"
    Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set sh_d = ActiveSheet
   
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=sh_s.Name & "!R1C1:R" & lr1 & "C12", Version:=ptver1).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=sh_d.Name & "!R3C1", TableName:=tbName1, _
        DefaultVersion:=ptver1

    With sh_d.PivotTables(tbName1).PivotFields("CRD_RWG")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
        .ClearAllFilters
        .CurrentPage = 1
    End With
   
    With sh_d.PivotTables(tbName1).PivotFields("NEW_DEFAULT")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
   
    With sh_d.PivotTables(tbName1)
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("CRD_EKSP_PIER_DC_FIN"), "Suma z Ekspozycji", xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("CRD_KOR_DC_FIN"), "Suma z Korekty", xlSum
    End With
```